# Reducing Provisioned Throughput for CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmosDB that had 4 containers and 400RUs provisioned at the database level.  I added 2 containers and without warning the provisioned RUs was increased to 600.

The document below explains why this happened.  Each container above the 4th requires a minimum extra 100RUs.  I have tight budget restrictions so I deleted 2 containers but I could not find a way to reduce the minimum provisioned throughput as the dropdown for provisioning throughput only allows increases.  Is there a way to reduce throughput?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#update-throughput-on-a-database-or-a-container),you could reduce throughput settings by using cosmos db sdk. For example, i test java sdk to reduce my container throughput setting. Please refer to below code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class ChangeRUTest {

    static private String YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
    static private String YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY="***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT,
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY,
                new ConnectionPolicy(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        String collectionLink = "dbs/test/colls/one";

        String collectionResourceId = client.readCollection(collectionLink, null).getResource().getResourceId();

        // find offer associated with this collection
        Iterator<Offer> it = client.queryOffers(
                String.format("SELECT * FROM r where r.offerResourceId = '%s'", collectionResourceId), null).getQueryIterator();

        Offer offer = it.next();

        System.out.println(offer.getContent().getInt("offerThroughput"));

        // update the offer
        int newThroughput = 400;
        offer.getContent().put("offerThroughput", newThroughput);
        client.replaceOffer(offer);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a method for Cosmos DB with MongoDB Api?

Comment: @HamishAnderson Tried to find for you.

Comment: Is there a way to get a range throughput?