# How to provision throughput at the database level in java code using azure-documentdb

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I wish to create azure cosmos databases from Java code using the com.microsoft.azure:azure-documentdb:2.4.1. I can only find the option to set offerThroughput which is for collections created in the database.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://sajeetharan.com/2019/06/18/auto-scale-cosmosdb-with-azure-function-v2-0/

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentClientException {

        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT,
                YOUR_COSMOS_DB_MASTER_KEY,
                new ConnectionPolicy(),
                ConsistencyLevel.Session);

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.setOfferThroughput(500);

        Database database = new Database();
        database.setId("testdb");
        client.createDatabase(database,requestOptions);
}
```

If you want to update RU settings, you could refer to my previous case:

1.[Reducing Provisioned Throughput for CosmosDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698081/reducing-provisioned-throughput-for-cosmosdb/55702999#55702999)

2.[Cosmos Db Throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830016/cosmos-db-throughput/53830754#53830754)

Comment: Thanks Jay, that does create a database with shared throughput . I did see the offer methods on DocumentClient but I didn't find anything that worked.

Comment: My code now fails creating a collection as it must have a partition key when throughput is shared: I have added one programmatically but it fails. I can create a Container using the azure portal with the same partition key and my code can create documents in that Container....

Comment: but queries fail with this error: com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception

Comment: I have concluded not to use shared throughput 1) for integration tests I will tear everything down immediately 2) move low volume tables out of cosmos ( I am in the process of moving a HBase database into cosmos)

Comment: @stephennewman Would you please jump into this room:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197589/how-to-provision-throughput-at-the-database-level-in-java-code-using-azure-docume?